# how to override a directive scope function in angular

Tags: angularjs

How do I override a directive controller function $scope.functionABC() which is in a third party node module? Basically, when functionABC() is called, I want to hijack it and run my custom functionABC(). The challenge here is that in my custom function I will also need access to the local variables in the original function. What would be the best option to achieve this? Is there a way to extend or override the original directive? or just re-write a new directive (which I would like to avoid).

here is an example

```
            $scope.modityDropdownLabel = function () {
                var myCustomLabel = '( ' + $scope.dropdownModel.value,length;) + ')';
                return $translate($scope.prefix + "." + countLabel;
            };
```

Comment: Give us some code of what you're trying to do because it seems twisted...

Comment: Define local variables? How are they accessible? Properties of the scope? Global variables to a iife? Through a closure?